# Tools to organize Dataset designer?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, dataset, dataset-designer

Does anybody know of good tools/plugins to organize the dataset designer in Visual Studio 2008? Right now it's a big jumble of TableAdapters without relationship views - it would be very cool if there was a tool available that could organize it, kinda like how it's done in SQL Server Management studio's 'Diagram' pane.

Cheers,
WT

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are aware of it, but in Visual Studio when you add a new DataSet you can use the Configure option of the TableAdapter. Using that you can see the Query designer which helps with what you want.

If that's not it, I remember using Altova for something like that. This might help you: http://www.altova.com/
Or this: http://www.stylusstudio.com/

Comment: Hi, yes, I was aware of the "Configure" option. I was referring to the graphical organization of DataTables and TableAdapters in the Dataset. Do these tools help with that?

Comment: I think they can help since the Dataset is XML and XSD. Trying the demos won't hurt :)